# Replacing nth occurrence of word with a replacement word in Java

Tags: java, match

I am doing homework related to Java language. I am reading a text file from a website via socket with:

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inr);`

```
while((line2 = br.readLine()) != null)
{...}
```

I need to replace the nth occurrence of the target word with a replacement word only if n is odd. 
For example:

line2 is readed as "ces11111111". target word is 11 ; replacement word is CS219.
Thus , result line is cesCS21911CS21911.

How can I achieve this ? Please help me to complete my homework.

Comment: `"I need to replace the nth occurrence of the  ???? with only ???? if n is odd."` - Of the what? With only what? This line is confusing.

Comment: I am correcting my question: I need to replace nth occurrence of target word with a replacement word only if n is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
public static String replaceIfOdd(String stringToChange,
        String searchingWord, String replacingWord) {
    final String separator = "#######";
    String splittingString = stringToChange.replaceAll(searchingWord,
            separator + searchingWord);
    String[] splitArray = splittingString.split(separator);
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            splitArray[i] = splitArray[i].replace(searchingWord,
                    replacingWord);
        result += splitArray[i];
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

Way to call it:

```
replaceIfOdd("ces11111111", "11", "CS219");
```

The logic behind this is the following:

I replace all the occurrences of the `searchingWord` with `separator + searchingWord`.
After that I just split the resulting string using the `split` function.
Then I loop through all the elements of the array and I make the right replacement only when the `searchingWord` appears in an odd position into the array and, at the same time, I just recreate the string with the right replacements done.

Hope this is what you were searching for!

P.S.: I used a string `separator` in order to break down the `stringToChange`, obviously if into your `stringToChange` there was such a string, the method wouldn't give you the right result ... I will try to think about a different implementation if you are worried about it. Ciao!

Comment: missed by 13 seconds !

Answer (score 0):

```
    String in = "ces11ccc11ceb11";
    in = "ces11111111";
    String target = "11";
    String replacement = "CS219";
    int j=0;
    boolean flag=true;
    String result = "";

    for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++)
    {

        if(in.length()-i<target.length()) break;
        if(in.charAt(i)==target.charAt(0))
        {
            if(in.substring(i, i+target.length()).equals(target))
            {
                if(flag)
                {   
                    result += replacement;
                }
                else result += target;
                flag=!flag; 
                i = i+target.length()-1;
            }
            else result += in.charAt(i);

        }
        else
        {
            result += in.charAt(i);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: No these target and replacement words come as a command line argument , target word = args[2] = 11 , replacement word = args[3] = CS219 and I do not know the line content , this one which I gave is an example only.

Comment: Thank you but , again I am saying maybe the line is ces11ccc11ceb11 and the result must be cesCS219ccc11cebCS219. Thus , I need a general solution to be available for every situation

Comment: Yes this code works for ces11ccc11ceb11 but does not work for ces11111111

Comment: Sorry :) check again, it was a minor bug.