# Replace every nth character occurrence in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a rather finnicky and fragile string formatter, where the only way that I can split data entries from a source is to know the size of the entry, and then remove it from the input data.
For example, the output looks something like:

```
field1 / field2 / field3 / field4 / 
field1 / field2 / field3 / field4 /
field1 / field2 / field3 / field4 /
```

And I would like to split the output on every nth /, in this case every 4th /.
I cannot split based on \n since the output can insert \n characters in order to wrap the output to the screen, and I am not allowed to alter the output code or receive it in another format.

So far I had the idea of splitting the entire raw input based on /, then assembling every n entries as an object, however I do not feel as if this is a particularly elegant solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing nth occurrence of word with a replacement word in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856042/replacing-nth-occurrence-of-word-with-a-replacement-word-in-java)

Comment: @YassineBadache That seems like the method of breaking everything up on /, then bundling every n entries as individual objects. Is there any neater solutions, or is that the only real way?

Comment: @Andrew in regex you can use something like `(?:[^\/]*\/){3}` (where `3` is whatever number you choose), but string methods are usually better practice for splitting on a specific character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't expect a built-in library method for every task you want to accomplish. Sometimes the neatest way is just to write it yourself.

```
public List<String> splitEvery(String source, char delimiter, int num) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder item = new StringBuilder();
    int delimCount = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<source.length(); i++) {
        char c = source.charAt(i);
        if(c == delimiter) {
            delimCount++;
        }
        if(delimCount == num) {
            delimCount = 0;
            list.add(item.toString());
            item = new StringBuilder();
        } else {
            item.append(c);
        }
    }
    list.add(item.toString());
    return list;
}
```

Or:

```
public List<String> splitEvery(String source, char delimiter, int num) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int delimCount = 0;
    int startOfCurrentItem = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<source.length(); i++) {
        char c = source.charAt(i);
        if(c == delimiter) {
            delimCount++;
        }
        if(delimCount == num) {
            delimCount = 0;
            list.add(source.substring(startOfCurrentItem, i));
            startOfCurrentItem = i+1;
        } 
    }
    list.add(source.substring(startOfCurrentItem, source.length()));
    return list;
}
```

This may need tweaking for edge cases (empty input string, etc.). Write some tests and make them pass -- I'm not doing all the work!

Comment: Thank you for your passive aggressive comment of "Why are you expecting other people to do all the work, don't be lazy!" when the question was "Is there a more efficient algorithm than this?". There's nothing wrong with asking if there is a more efficient approach to a problem, instead of going for a solution that feels like a hack.

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question, but there's no need to be impolite about it.

Comment: No aggression, passive or otherwise, intended. I just wanted to explain that you can't copy-paste this and expect it work for all inputs, without a bit of extra tweaking.